# How can I maintain a CoreData table which can be edited outside its relationship to another table?

Tags: iphone, core-data, contacts, relationships

Let's say I have a table called "Event" which has a to-many relationship with table "Group" which has a to-many relationship with table "Person".

Many groups can be created which could reference the same person.

I have not added an inverse relationship yet from "Person" to "Group" since if a "Group" is deleted I do not want the associated "Person" to be deleted as it may be referenced somewhere else.

Should I just leave out the inverse relationship?  The docs advise strongly against this but I think this many be an instance where it is the right way to go.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Also, should the delete rule for Group be set to "No Action"?  This way the "Person" table is not altered when a group is deleted.

Comment: I think I may have it now...Group has to-many relationship with Person. Person has inverse to-many relationship to Group. Now I need to determine delete rules.  I have Group-Person as "No Action" and Person-Group as "Deny". I think maybe Group-Person should be "Nullify" and that CoreData is smart enough to leave "Player" alone if it is referenced by another Group?  I think that is the core question I am asking :-)  Thanks...

Comment: Christopher, you normally want the default value of "Nullify". "No Action" is intended for when you're going to implement custom behavior in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise, you should *always* have an inverse relationship. It helps CoreData maintain the integrity of the object graph. The default delete rule for a relationship is "Nullify", which sounds like what you want. "Nullify" means that if you delete this object, the relationship attribute on the other end of this relationship gets nilled-out (for a to-one relationship) or has the value removed from the set (for a to-many relationship). The only way for the other end of the relationship to actually be deleted is if you change the delete rule to specify that.

**tl;dr**: Use inverse relationships, leave the Delete Rule at the default of "Nullify".